# Linked List in C too slow

Tags: c, performance, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on an application in C. This application requires fast insertion of a linked list, however, due to the example code below, I can only get 16384 or 2^14
insertions in 0.5 seconds. I need at least 100000 - 1000000 insertions a second. I was wondering if there is any way to increase performance of the linked list. I was thinking that I should add an "index" to the linked list, just like an array index, and have it append from there.

**Note**: This is a single-chain classical linked list.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS 32768

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* create_list(int genesis_data) {
    struct Node* list = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list->data = genesis_data;
    list->next = NULL;
    return list;
}

void append(struct Node* head, int _data_) {
    struct Node* new_block = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    current = head;
    new_block->data = _data_;
    new_block->next = NULL;
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        head->next = new_block;
    }
    else {
        while(true) {
            if(current->next == NULL) {
                current->next = new_block;
                break;
            }
            else {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_list_data(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    current = head;
    while(true) {
        if(current->next == NULL) {
            printf("Node: %d\n", current->data);
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Node: %d\n", current->data);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Node* list = create_list(15);
    printf("List created!\n");
    append(list, 5);
    printf("Single element appended to list!\n");
    printf("Appending %d items to the list...\n", NUM_OF_ELEMENTS);
    double t1 = clock();
    for(int x = 0; x < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; x++) {
        append(list, 5);
    }
    double t2 = clock();
    printf("Time taken to append %d elements to the list: %f\n", NUM_OF_ELEMENTS, (t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    //print_list_data(list);    // to print data to the list
    return 0;
}
```

**Specs**:

- 16 GB DDR4 RAM
- Intel Core I7
- Intel Integrated Graphics

Comment: If you're willing to "cheat" a bit, you could keep track of the address of the tail, so that you don't have to traverse the entirety of the list for each append.

Comment: @Sean Seems like an interesting idea! I will try to implement it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have a “Shlemiel the Painter” problem. Your code exhibits quadratic behaviour using O(N*N) time to insert N elements. You can’t afford that. Keep a record of the end of the list, or insert at the front of the list instead of the rear.

Answer (score 4):

There is easy to speed up with a different implementation of a linked list.

There is no need for a special head node.

Instead of the last node's `next` member pointing to `NULL`, have it point to the first node of the linked list.  Keep track of the "tail" to know when to stop iterating the list.  The "head" of the list is easy to find: `tail->next`

Instead of saving the "head" as the "list", save the "tail" - this is a variation on a *single-chain classical linked list*.

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* create_list(int genesis_data) {
  struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof *list);
  list->data = genesis_data;
  list->next = list;
  return list;
}

// Add node to end of list
// pass in the address of the list
void append(struct Node** list, int _data_) {
  struct Node* tail = *list;
  struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
  new_node->data = _data_;
  new_node->next = tail->next;
  tail->next = new_node;
  *list = new_node;
}

// Add node to front of list
void prepend(struct Node* list, int _data_) {
  struct Node* tail = *list;
  struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
  new_node->data = _data_;
  new_node->next = tail->next;
  tail->next = new_node;
}

int list_head_value(const struct Node* list) {
  const struct Node* tail = list;
  return tail->next->data;
}

int list_tail_value(const struct Node* list) {
  const struct Node* tail = list;
  return tail->data;
}

void print_list_data(const struct Node* list) {
  const struct Node* tail = list;
  const struct Node* current = tail->next;
  do {
    printf("Node: %d\n", current->data);
    current = current->next;
  } while (current != tail);
}
```

---

Hopefully this is enough to present the idea.

Additional work  needed to provide code to pop the list to zero nodes.

The keep points are:
To append to the end of the list is O(1)
To prepend to the beginning of the list is O(1)
To pop off the front of the list is O(1)
To report the top of the list is O(1)
To report the end of the list is O(1) 
To test if the list is empty is O(1)
To pop off the end of the list is O(N)
To report the list size is O(N)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to speed up the insert opertion then you cannot loop through the
whole list every time you append something. Your `append` function adds the new
element at the end of the list, so the head node could have a pointer to the
tail of the list:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *tail;  // used only by the head node
};

struct Node* create_list(int genesis_data) {
    struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    list->data = genesis_data;
    list->next = NULL;
    list->tail = list;
    return list;
}
```

Also remove this line

```
struct Node* current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

from you `append` and `print_list_data` functions, that serves no purpose other than leak memory. And
don't use variable names that start with an underscore, variable names that
start with an underscore are reserved by the language/compiler.

```
int append(struct Node* head, int data) {
    if(head == NULL)
        return 0;

    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if(node == NULL)
        return 0;

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    head->tail->next = node;
    head->tail = node; // updating tail of head

    return 1;
}
```

This function is in `O(1)`. But it comes with a price: you made your node
structure bigger and need more space.

Of course if you remove nodes and you happen to remove the head, don't forget to
update the `tail` member of the new head.

And if you want speed for the insert operations, I probably would use arrays
instead of linked lists.

**edit**

As [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702933/linked-list-in-c-too-slow/49703029#comment86419672_49703029) points out in the comments, this solution comes with a price, the
structures get bigger and you have a lot of wasted space because only the head
uses the `tail` member. Another solution would be to wrap the linked list around
a second structure that contains the pointer to the tail:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List {
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
}

struct Node* create_node(int genesis_data) {
    struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    list->data = genesis_data;
    list->next = NULL;
    return list;
}

struct List *create_list(int genesis_data)
{
    struct List *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    list->head = create_node(genesis_data);

    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
        return NULL;
    }

    list->tail = list->head;

    return list;
}

int append(struct List* list, int data) {
    if(list == NULL)
        return 0;

    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if(node == NULL)
        return 0;

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail = node; // updating tail of head

    return 1;
}

void print_list_data(struct List* list) {
    if(list == NULL)
        return;

    struct Node *current = list->head;

    while(current)
    {
        printf("Node: %d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or Have a LinkedList struct that implements the operations on a linked list of Node structs, where LinkedList stores a single Node* tail.  Otherwise you waste a huge amount of space on unused pointers.

Comment: @DaveS good point, I was also thinking about that, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Another consideration is the amount of time memory allocation takes.  (It in itself is often traversing a list of some sort).  Perhaps you could also modify your answer to allocate an array of the payload data structures (int) in each node and a "fullness" indicator along with the pointer to the last node.  That way you not only get to the end quicker, you allocate, say, 50 at a time, making the insert allocation 50 x faster.  Of course if you ever need to remove an item you need a more complicated structure.

Comment: @LoztInSpace yes, there are many optimization left to be made, pre allocating memory would also make the inserts faster, I agree with your suggestion. Perhaps you can write you own answer with your suggestion, my answer is already long enough.

Answer (score 0):

run a profiling to see where your program spend most time on.  "premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Donald Knuth)

in this case, i would venture a guess that memory allocation is the culprit.  if profiling result agrees with my guess then the answer became apparent.  you can allocate a sizable block of memory with malloc and store your node data in it.  i must warn you though that it's not simple.  memory management and con-currant access will be your enemy.  that's why it's offered in many library already.

Comment: The performance problem with this code should be obvious on inspection -- and no, it isn't memory allocation.